# Fortran function to get association status and size of a pointer in one go

Tags: class, fortran, polymorphism, intel-fortran

I am writing a Fortran (2003) integer function to check a pointer to an array of arbitrary elements for association status and size, using `class(*)`. If not associated, it shall return -1, otherwise the number of elements of the array. It is assumed that the pointer is defined pointing to `null()`.

The goal is to avoid two subsequent `if` statements. (I am aware that in C the 2 checks can be combined to a single statement.)

The code compiles and runs under gfortran (6.1.0) and Intel ifort (17.0.4), but only gfortran gives the desired result.

The complete code comprising a test routine and the function called "size_field" is shown below:

```
program tpa  
implicit none  
real,pointer :: tp(:)=>null()  

                      write (6,*) size_field(tp)  
allocate   (tp(53));  write (6,*) size_field(tp)  
deallocate (tp);      write (6,*) size_field(tp)  
tp=>null();           write (6,*) size_field(tp)  
allocate   (tp(0));   write (6,*) size_field(tp)  
deallocate (tp);      write (6,*) size_field(tp)  

contains

   function size_field(ff)  
   integer :: size_field  
   class(*),target  :: ff(:)  
   class(*),pointer :: field(:)  
   field => ff  
   size_field=-1 ! shall indicate not associated  
   if (associated(field)) size_field=size(field)  
   end function  

end program
```

Compiled with gfortran (default compiler options), the output is as intended:

```
-1
53
-1
-1
 0  
-1
```

Compiled with ifort (default compiler options), the output is:

```
 0  
53  
53  
53  
 0  
 0
```

Why is ifort not giving the result I intended?
If I replace `class(*)` with `real`, also the ifort compiled program shows the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is not valid Fortran.  A compiler is allowed to give any result it likes when asked to compile this program.

The dummy argument `ff`

```
   class(*), target :: ff(:)
```

is a non-pointer, non-optional dummy argument and so (Fortran 2018 15.5.2.3 p1) any pointer actual argument when referencing the function `size_field`, in this case `tp`, must be pointer associated with a target.

On the first reference, `tp` is not pointer associated.

As to how to meet your requirements, the "non-optional" part is a big hint.  Under Fortran 2008+ one may make the dummy argument optional, and then the actual argument need not be pointer associated when referencing the function.  If the actual argument is not pointer associated then the dummy argument is not present:

```
function size_field(ff)
  integer :: size_field
  class(*), target, optional :: ff(:)

  if (PRESENT(ff)) then
    size_field = SIZE(ff)
  else
    size_field = -1
  end if

end function
```

However, addressing the "non-optional" part of the restriction is the sole helpful way in the case of the question.  Trying to make the dummy argument a pointer instead is not helpful: for a polymorphic dummy pointer argument the actual argument must also be polymorphic (and with an unlimited polymorphic dummy the actual argument must also be unlimited polymorphic).

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. However, your proposal does not work either. I should like to add that compiling with debug options changes the results. gfortran -C -g -fcheck=all -Wall tpa.f90 gives the same result as above.  ifort -C -g -warn all -debug -all tpa.f90 results in a segmentation fault. It seems that I have to recode the subprogram or to live with the tried and tested way using two if statements.

Comment: The proposal here uses a F2008 feature; I'll have to check which compiler versions are required.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when trying your new version. I can now confirm that it works indeed as expected on my platform with both gfortran (6.1.0) and ifort (17.0.4). Thank you for your help. I was not aware of this use of the optional keyword in Fortran 2008.

Comment: Yes, this is the behaviour of a Fortran 2008 compiler (see Fortran 2008 12.5.2.12, similar in Fortran 2018).  (Although more precisely, it's the _dummy_ argument that is not present.)

Comment: Fortran 2008  indeed introduces this feature: "A null pointer can be used to denote an absent nonallocatable nonpointer optional argument." (JTC 1/SC 22/WG5/N1791). This is also described in the documentations of gfortran and Intel fortran compilers.